# How many 7-symbol codes can be formed?

Tags: combinatorics

Codes consist of 4 digits followed by 3 letters.

Given that any letter can be used in the 3 letters (with repetition), and the digits are the arrangements of all the digits of the number 4477.

I got 26^3*(4!/2!2!).

Is that correct? If not, what is the correct answer and how do I get to it?

Comment: The answer is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Because all valid arrangements consist of four digits followed by three letters, you can multiply the number of ways of choosing the digits with the number of ways of choosing the letters. The ordering of digits is completely determined by the placement of the 7's into two of four places, in $\binom{4}{2}$ ways. Each choice of letter is independent, and order matters, so there are $26^3$ ways of choosing the letters.

Hence the answer of $\binom{4}{2}\cdot 26^3=\frac{4!}{2!2!}26^3$.